# How do you select and delete drawings in google sheets with a script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm writing a google script that copies a sheet and pastes it into another spreadsheet, but I have to automatically delete the drawings that are present there. How do I do that? I couldn't find any documentation on the matter.
I have tried using the getCharts() function, but while debugging I realized that it remained empty.

```
var charts = thisSheet.getCharts();
for (var i in charts) {
  thisSheet.removeChart(charts[i]);
}
```

Comment: If you are referring to drawing (a rectangle to be use as a button in a Sheet), this is still a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1054). You may want to star that request to be updated regarding its progress. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks! It's not a vital problem, but it's certainly an inconvenience. I sure hope they will add this possibility to the API.

Answer (score 1):

```
var drawings = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDrawings();
...
drawing.remove();
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/drawing

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this address:
[Developpers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/drawing#getonaction)
I adapted a little bit his code to my needs (delete a specific Button) and works well.
Also, it works for drawings and images in GSheets.
my code :

```
function delDrawing(sheet,actionName) {
var drawings = sheet.getDrawings();
for (var i = 0; i < drawings.length; i++) {
Logger.log(drawings[i].getOnAction());
if (drawings[i].getOnAction()===actionName){
drawings[i].remove();
}
}
}
```

it work similar for images

```
function delImages(sheet,ScriptName) {
var imagins = sheet.getImages();
for (var i = 0; i < imagins.length; i++) {
Logger.log("imagins[i].getScript():" + imagins[i].getScript());
if (imagins[i].getScript() === ScriptName) {
imagins[i].remove();
}
}
}
```

Also take a look to [Yagisanatode](https://yagisanatode.com/how-to-remove-a-google-sheets-button-drawings-or-images-connected-to-a-google-apps-script-after-the-script-has-been-run/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var drawings = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDrawings();
for (var i = 0; i < drawings.length; i++) {
  drawings[i].remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am NOT a programmer, but I found a similar script for images and just changed "Images" to "Drawings" and it works!! It deletes all drawings in all active Sheets

```
function deleteInCellDrawingsAllSheets() {
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    const sheet = sheets[i];
    sheet.getDrawings().forEach(e => e.remove()); // removes all IN CELL Drawings in the sheet.
  }
}
```